# Angular 8: No component factory found for the component-even added in app.module.ts

Tags: ng-modules, angular8

I am trying to migrate the project from Angular 7 to Angular 8.

However, getting the below error for the HeaderComponent after upgrading to Angular 8.

zone.js:199 Uncaught Error: No component factory found for HeaderComp. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:17988)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:18026)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:18023)
    at AngularFrameworkComponentWrapper.push../node_modules/ag-grid-angular/dist/angularFrameworkComponentWrapper.js.AngularFrameworkComponentWrapper.createComponent (angularFrameworkComponentWrapper.js:65)
    at DynamicAgNg2Component.createComponent (angularFrameworkComponentWrapper.js:44)
    at DynamicAgNg2Component.push../node_modules/ag-grid-angular/dist/angularFrameworkComponentWrapper.js.BaseGuiComponent.init (angularFrameworkComponentWrapper.js:84)
    at DynamicAgNg2Component.init (angularFrameworkComponentWrapper.js:40)
    at UserComponentFactory.push../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/components/framework/userComponentFactory.js.UserComponentFactory.initComponent (userComponentFactory.js:371)
    at UserComponentFactory.push../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/components/framework/userComponentFactory.js.UserComponentFactory.createAndInitUserComponent (userComponentFactory.js:121)
    at UserComponentFactory.push../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/components/framework/userComponentFactory.js.UserComponentFactory.newHeaderComponent (userComponentFactory.js:37)

Please find the HeaderComponent and app.module.ts below.

This is for Angular 8 so it was working in Angular 7 and after my searches on Google I improved app.module.ts by declaring entryComponent.

HeaderComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Inject, forwardRef, Input } from 
'@angular/core';
import { pagesToggleService } from '../../services/toggler.service'
import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs/Subscriber'
declare var pg: any;
@Component({
selector: 'pg-header',
templateUrl: './header.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
_headerClass = "";
isHorizontalLayout: false;
_service;
@Input()
boxed: boolean = false;

@Input()
extraClass: string = "";

constructor(private toggler: pagesToggleService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.isHorizontalLayout = pg.isHorizontalLayout;
    this._service = this.toggler.headerClass
        .subscribe(state => {
            this._headerClass = state;
        });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this._service.unsubscribe()
}
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
  HeaderComponent
]

entryComponents: [
    HeaderComponent
]
```

I expect it to work in Angular 8 but it is throwing 'No component factory found for HeaderComp.' error.

Please help me to find a solution.

Thanks,

Kind Regards.

Begum

Comment: Have you imported the HeaderComponent in app.module.ts file?

Comment: Yes; import { HeaderComponent } from '../.pages/@pages/components/header/header.component';

Answer (score 0):

In declaration part add first the app component in app.module.ts like :

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent,HeaderComponent],
entryComponents: [HeaderComponent]
})
```

Thanks

Comment: then done one thing add the service in the provider that you are using in the component and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The error says the HeadComp instead of HeaderComponent so it is a grid issue and I fixed it by using ngx-datatable in html.